# Can't move Instatiated Object from queue, changes transform of prefab instead

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a "Mania" style game(like guitar hero). But i can't seem to get the Movement of the "notes" to work, I keep the notes in a queue and I dequeue the last note and change it's position to the top again. But for some reason it doesen't work with my "goodcubes". only the normal ones

*The problem seems to be that the instead of moving the "goodCube" to the correct position it instead changes the transform of the prefab.*

**All "notes" are referred to as "Cubes" in script**

```
for (int i = 0; i < backlog; i++)//how many rows to spawn
{
    goodCubes.Enqueue(Instantiate(goodcube));
    for (int j = 0; j < columns - 1; j++)
    {
        badCubes.Enqueue(Instantiate(cube));
    }
}

//I check the player input and if it corresponds with a note in the correct row
//I have tested so both true and false option gets called
if (i == position) 
{
    GameObject good = goodCubes.Dequeue();
    good.transform.position = spawnPoint;
    spawnPoint += new Vector2(1 * rowOffset, 0);
    goodCubes.Enqueue(goodcube);
}
else
{
    GameObject badCube = badCubes.Dequeue();
    badCube.transform.position = spawnPoint;`enter code here`
    spawnPoint += new Vector2(1 * rowOffset, 0);
    badCubes.Enqueue(badCube);
}
```

*The full script*

```
    public int columus;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject goodcube;
    public event Action moveCubes;

    [SerializeField] private int score = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float rowOffset = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float heightDifference = 1;
    [SerializeField] private int backlog = 4;

    private float SpawnHeight;
    Queue<int> positions = new Queue<int>();
    Queue<GameObject> badCubes = new Queue<GameObject>();
    Queue<GameObject> goodCubes = new Queue<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < backlog; i++)
        {
            goodCubes.Enqueue(Instantiate(goodcube));
            for (int j = 0; j < columus - 1; j++)
            {
                badCubes.Enqueue(Instantiate(cube));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < backlog; i++)
        {
            positions.Enqueue(SpawnRow(i * heightDifference));
        }
    }

    int SpawnRow(float y)
    {
        int position = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, columus);
        Vector2 spawnPoint = new Vector2(-columus * rowOffset / 2f, y);
        for (int i = 0; i < columus; i++)
        {
            if (i == position)
            {
                GameObject goodCube = goodCubes.Dequeue();
                goodCube.transform.position = spawnPoint;
                spawnPoint += new Vector2(1 * rowOffset, 0);
                goodCubes.Enqueue(goodcube);
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject badCube = badCubes.Dequeue();
                badCube.transform.position = spawnPoint;
                spawnPoint += new Vector2(1 * rowOffset, 0);
                badCubes.Enqueue(badCube);
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            UpdateScore(0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            UpdateScore(1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            UpdateScore(2);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
        {
            UpdateScore(3);
        }
    } //inputcheck

    private void UpdateScore(int input)
    {
        if (positions.Dequeue() == input)
        {
            moveCubes?.Invoke();
            positions.Enqueue(SpawnRow(backlog * heightDifference + 1 * heightDifference));
            score++;
        }
        else
        {
            moveCubes?.Invoke();
            positions.Enqueue(SpawnRow(backlog * heightDifference + 1 * heightDifference));
            score--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code wont compile, theres missing braces to start with on "badCubes.Enqueue(Instantiate(note);" ..

Comment: @BugFinder Fixed the missing bracket renamed note to be consistent with full script, still those where just mistakes i made in the process of posting the question

Comment: put a different variable name for goodcube in spawn row, while the local one should override you can make sure it is by using a different name than the prefab name

Comment: @BugFinder tested, and as expected it diden't change anything

Comment: well, if you made that change, none of that code moves the prefab.  it moves instances.. (although it seems a very confused way to do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I truly believe your issue is a typo in your code. That usually happens when you have variables with the same name. Your issue is that you are enqueuing the prefab goodcube and not the goodCube object:

```
GameObject goodCube = goodCubes.Dequeue();
goodCube.transform.position = spawnPoint;
spawnPoint += new Vector2(1 * rowOffset, 0);
//******HERE YOU ARE ENQUEUEING THE PREFAB goodcube AND NOT goodCube as your variable name suggests two lines above this line*****
goodCubes.Enqueue(goodCube);//INSTEAD OF goodCubes.Enqueue(goodcube);
```